# MockServer throws "Connection refused" while SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mockserver

I just can't get the `org.mock-server` running. It gives me:

```
org.mockserver.client.netty.SocketConnectionException: Unable to connect to socket localhost/127.0.0.1:443
```

Here is the code of my test case:

```
private ClientAndServer mockServer;

@BeforeClass
public void startServer() {
    mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);
}

@Test
void downloadByUserShouldRetry() {
    // given
    new MockServerClient("localhost", 443)
        .when(
            request()
                .withSecure(true)
                .withMethod("GET")
                .withPath("myUrl")
                .withHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + adminAccessToken),
                exactly(1)
            )
            .respond(
                response()
                    .withStatusCode(401)
                    .withHeaders(
                        new Header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"),
                        new Header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=86400")
                    )
                    .withBody("{ message: 'incorrect username and password combination' }")
                    .withDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS,1)
            );
```

Comment: Why do you want to connect with the `MockServerClient` to your Spring Boot application and not to the MockServer? You usually connect with this client to the running MockServer to stub the HTTP communication from your Spring Boot application to the outside world. Invoking your application during the test then usually happens with the `WebTestClient` or `TestRestTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I have stumbled on a similar issue. I had multiple integration test using a single MockServer static instance.

I found the following answer on [this Github issue](https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver/issues/498#issuecomment-801255001) which did the trick for me:

```java
        mockServer.stop();
        while (!mockServer.hasStopped(3,100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){}
```

Basically you're waiting for the server for stopping completely before moving on to the next test. That did the trick for me quite nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me :(

Comment: Did you check the Github Issue I'm referencing in my post? Maybe you can find other answers there.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes bcz of wrong import of Test class, it should be org.junit.Test, its worked for me

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem, the error message in the question indicates that the test actually starts running (and tries to connect to `:443`)

Comment: changing Test pkg worked for me , thats y suggested